# Variable step in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to loop between 0.01 and 10, but between 0.01 and 0.1 use 0.01 as the step, then between 0.1 and 1.0 use 0.1 as step, and between 1.0 and 10.0 use 1.0 as step.

I have the while loop code written, but want to make it more pythonic.

```
i = 0.01
while i < 10:
   # do something
   print i
   if i < 0.1:
       i += 0.01
   elif i < 1.0:
       i += 0.1
   else:
       i += 1
```

This will produce

```
0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: put that in a function and add a `yield i` as last instruction of the loop. That would be a generator, which you can iterate

Comment: Watch out - incrementing by steps doesn't work very well with floating-point rounding constraints. You're likely to have boundary errors.

Comment: @njzk2 - `yield` should be the **first** instruction in his loop, where the `# do something` is now. His first value needs to be `.01`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 21):

A special-purse generator function might be the right way to go. This would effectively separate the boring part (getting the list of numbers right) from the interesting part (the `# do something` in your example).

```
def my_range():
    for j in .01, .1, 1.:
        for i in range(1, 10, 1):
            yield i * j

for x in my_range():
    print x
```

Comment: This mostly works. You do get odd results like ``0.30000000000000004`` though.

Comment: Of course. That's the nature of floating-point arithmetic. `0.3` isn't  representable in a `float`.

Comment: Yup, no surprise on my part. I made this comment for the OP.

Comment: You can get slightly better results at the expense of a slight bit of clarity by using division instead of multiplication: `for j in 100., 10., 1.: for i in range(1, 10): yield i / j`. It doesn't matter much. The important thing is to avoid floating-point steps, and you're already doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a nested loop, the outer one that iterates over the precision and inner one that is just `range(1,10)`:

```
for precision in (0.01, 0.1, 1):
    for i in range(1,10):
        i*=precision
        print(i)
```

However floats are probably not going to work in this case as this shows values like `0.30000000000000004` on my machine, for precise decimal values you would want to use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module:

```
import decimal
for precision in ("0.01", "0.1", "1"):
    for i in range(1,10):
        i*=decimal.Decimal(precision)
        print(i)
```

Comment: yeah fixed that now too, jeez my head just isn't in it today.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use two loops:  one for the order of magnitude, and one for the values from 1 to 9:

```
for exp in range(-2, 1):
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print("{:.2f}".format(i * 10 ** exp))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a single line of code through list comprehension -

```
for k in [i*j for j in (0.01, 0.1, 1) for i in range(1, 10)]
```

Can't be more pythonic!

Comment: You don't need the assignment. OP wants to use this to drive a loop: `for x in (i*j for j in (.01, .1, 1.) for i in range(1,10)): print x`

Comment: :( it seems pretty contrived to have 3 `for` statements in a single line. I preferred it the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you wished to replace the loop with **vectorized** code...

```
In [63]: np.ravel(10.**np.arange(-2, 1)[:,None] * np.arange(1, 10)[None,:])
Out[64]: 
array([ 0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05,  0.06,  0.07,  0.08,  0.09,
        0.1 ,  0.2 ,  0.3 ,  0.4 ,  0.5 ,  0.6 ,  0.7 ,  0.8 ,  0.9 ,
        1.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ,  5.  ,  6.  ,  7.  ,  8.  ,  9.  ])
```

Comment: Numpy is way overkill for this problem

Comment: Yes, my code can be regarded as kind of overkill if you just need to print out the numbers (BTW, mine isn't the only one NumPy-based solution proposed here). However, if the ``# do something`` block involves a call to a time-consuming function which takes the generated values as argument, I think the vectorized code might be more efficient. Anyway, it is simply another possible approach that some users of SO could find useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a generator function as well, but if the steps are not such convenient powers of each other I'd write it like

```
def my_range():
    i = 0
    while i < 0.1:
        i += 0.01
        yield i
    while i < 1:
        i += 0.1
        yield i
    while i < 10:
        i += 1
        yield i

for x in my_range():
    print x
```

It might be a bit more repetitive, but illustrates much better what is going on and that the yielded values are monotonically increasing (regardless what numbers you put in).

If it gets too repetitive, use

```
def my_range():
    i = 0
    for (end, step) in [(0.1, 0.01), (1, 0.1), (10, 1)]:
        while i < end:
            i += step
            yield i
```

Comment: Like any other assignment, `+=` assignments are statements in Python; you can't `yield` them.

Comment: @user2357112: Right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.arange(0.01, 0.1, 0.01)
list2 = np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.1)
list3 = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
i_list = np.concatenate((list1, list2, list3))  # note the double parenthesis
for i in i_list:
    ...
```

Basically you create the entire list of values that you need up front, `i_list`, then just iterate through them in your `for` loop.